# Add script to head of every page without using layout in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add Mixpanel to my rails application, Mixpanel provides [Javascript API integration](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript) script that needs to be in the header of each page.  To achieve this I have included the script as part of the layout.

There are some pages of my application that don't use any layout, and as such I'm unable to use the Mixpanel instance created by this script in those views.

Is there somewhere in Rails that I can put this code so that it loads in the head of every page, even those pages that don't use a layout?

Comment: In the `application.html.erb`?

Comment: Hi @SebastiánPalma, are you referring to the layout file `application.html.erb` or some other file?

Comment: Yes, because when you say there are some pages don't use layout, which are those layouts?

Comment: Some of my controller methods contain `render layout: false`, I don't know which layout they default to, but it isn't `application.html.erb`, I already have the code snippet in the `application.html.erb` layout head and it doesn't appear on these pages.

Comment: Why not put the JS in your `application.js`?

Comment: Hi @jdgray, I'm new to rails and still not too familiar with the asset pipeline. Just to confirm, if I put my script in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` it will automatically load into every page of my application?